# How to find out which end of a dead battery is the anode, and its voltage

Tags: voltage, battery-operated, batteries

The battery pack for an old rc car I played with as a kid, has died.  Salt crystals everywhere, smells like vinegar.  The pack consists of 8 batteries of AA-size connected in series.  The red markers in the pic below are mine.

[image: IMG1]

Both sides of the individual batteries look identical.  Tried to measure the direction of the voltage, but my multimeter is only getting brief, spotty measurements I dont think I can trust.  I´m unable to find info from the manufacturer, and there are no labels with relevant information.

[image: IMG2]
[image: IMG3]

cf. also 
[attempted voltage measurement](https://ibb.co/cSRJpT)
[attempted voltage measurement #2](https://ibb.co/g8rF3o)
[closer view of single battery](https://ibb.co/gG3UeT)

I´m hoping through the clever use of duct tape and paper clips to make a new battery pack.  Is there any way to be reasonably sure of the magnitude and direction of the voltage so as not to destroy the car?  Also, would it help if I knew what the battery salts taste like?

Comment: I woudl expect the red wire to connect to the positive terminal of the battery.

Comment: Please don't taste the battery salts.

Comment: Niobius - Although not the main point of your question (and therefore I'm not writing this in an answer): "*I´m hoping through the clever use of duct tape and paper clips to make a new battery pack.*" Unfortunately you are very **unlikely** to be able to make stable, low-enough resistance connections, using duct tape pressing paper clips against battery terminals. This is especially true with the higher currents and mechanical vibrations of an RC car. :-( Also, if you attempted to solder wires directly to batteries, it's likely to damage them, as explained in other questions on the site.

Comment: This style of 8-cell pack is still sold with this series of connector, but you need to match the polarity and also the gender of connector which goes on the car vs. battery, as all 4 combinations have been used.

Comment: `Both sides of the individual batteries look identical` .... no they do not .... one end is crimped

Answer (score 2):

I see the two wires are red and black.  Very likely the red is positive and the black negative.  This is a very common convention, but of course, there is no guarantee that any one pack is wired according to the convention.

One way to check this is to use a bench supply set to 9 V and a low current limit, like 100 mA.  See if the device operates with + applied where the red wire went and - to where the black wire went.

You say this device is old, so these are probably NiMH or possibly even NiCd batteries.  Either way, figure about 1.2 V per cell during most of their operating life.  With 8 cells, that comes out to 9.6 V.  9 V should be safe to apply to the device but still allow it to operate.

The 100 mA current limit will likely be exceeded if you try to run any of the motors.  However, the point of the test is to see if the electronics power up and react properly.  If that works, and the current limit is hit when you try to command any of the motors to run, then you can try increasing the current limit.  It might take as much as a few amps with motors running.

Putting any remnants of the old batteries in your mouth is a bad idea.

Comment: Orange-coloured salt deposits are very suggestive of cadmium, which is very toxic.  NiMH batteries use a variety of metal alloys, but I don't think any of the common ones produce orange salts.  Most of those are pretty toxic, too, in any case... tasting them would definitely be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If it's quite old, it's not lithium, it's nickel-cadmium or "NiCd," and in that case it's 1.2V cells, for a 9.6V battery pack of eight cells in series.

Don't build, just buy.  They're still common.  Search on (amazon?) for 9.6V nicd battery pack, and you'll find lots.  Usually they're shrinkwrapped into a slab.  They probably have a different connector though.

Maybe you'll even get the exact connector if you try: 9.6V nicd battery pack RC car

https://www.google.com/search?q=9.6v+nicd+battery+pack+rc+car

And  ...WASH HANDS [CADMIUM POISONING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium_poisoning)!!!  Not as bad as lead or mercury, but still.  Ache-y flu-like symptoms, "Cadmium Blues" and even nickel salts are pretty evil.  Wear gloves, and thoroughly damp sponge-wipe the battery chamber on the RC car multiple times.  Rinse your sponge well after, and perhaps throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar battery pack, recently measured. One end of each battery has a crimp ring, which is its positive end. Your battery pack seems to be a series-string of eight batteries:
[image]